# Переплет переменных в динамической форме

Tags: delphi, forms

Всем привет.
У меня есть динамический массив (к примеру `Form1: array of TForm1`) который хранит в себе образец формы, к примеру TForm1

Так же у меня есть лист бокс, один элемент лист бокса = 1 форма, двойное нажатие по элементу - форма создается и затем открывается таким образом

```
Form1[ItemIndex] := TForm1.Create(Application);
```

Form1.....(ну и там пошло в общем)
затем она открывается.

На форме у меня есть чек бокс (на форме которую я создаю) и во время нажатия на чекбокс переменной `CheckBox` я присваиваю значение `Checked`.

И если на одной форме я нажал на чекбокс, на ней присвоилось значение переменной, то на второй форме сделалось это же самое.

В общем суть в том, что все переменные переплетаются между собой, никто не знает, каким путем можно сделать ? 
Еще вариант - попробовать перенести форму на фрейм и там же это все создавать

Comment: Давид, добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Наверняка здесь есть люди, которые знают, как сделать то, что Вам нужно. Трудность в том, что Вы очень плохо объяснили, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, у Вас есть глобальная переменная CheckBox, которой Вы присваиваите значение при нажатии на checkBox который размещен на форме. Если это так - используйте список TDictinaty<TForm, Boolean> в котором будет хранится ссылка на форму и значение переменной. Но это уже какая то жесть. Пересмотрите архитектуру, приложения возможно вам не массив форм нужно хранить а массив объектов в которых хранится ссылка на форму и нужные элементы.

Comment: пробовали не использовать статические данные? покажите как вы создаете массов форм и саму форму. думаю есть и другое решение. без кода некуда

Comment: Какая версия Delphi используется? В зависимости от этого решение может отличаться по реализации.

Comment: @kami Delphi XE 3 upd 2

Comment: Код реализации и как я создаю данный массив (обьявляю) я выклал в самом вопросе.

Comment: И задаю ему размер с помощью процедуры SetLength()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, перенес все переменные в сам класс формы.
И когда я обращался к переменным из других классов, то не писал вот так: Form1.variable, а писал название динам. переменной и индекс формы, а индекс формы я передавал каждой форме при ее создании. Все работает, это самый простой вариант до которого я додумался. Всем спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать какой-то мета-класс (внешний класс) для хранения состояния чекбоксов, который будет содержать эти значения. По сути, модель для вашей вьюхи (формы):

```
public class MyMeta{
   bool mCheckBox1Checked;
}
```

Когда вы изменяете значение чекбокса, то меняете это поле в классе. При открытии формы, запрашивайте это поле и выставляйте соответствующие значение у чек бокса.

Comment: Другими словами вы предлагаете хранить состояние чекбоксов во внешнем классе.

Comment: @KromStern вы так сказали, будто это что-то плохое =/

Comment: Нет-нет! Я просто решил переформулировать попроще, для автора вопроса (слова типа мета-класс и модель, и код на Java(?) могут его запутать еще больше)

Comment: @KromStern когда за плечами годы опыта, сложно уже выражаться простым языком. А на Java, так как Delphi не обучен. Но это чисто концепт, без привязки к языку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне не подходит ваш вариант, что-то подобное я пробовал сделать, но вроде не получалось. У меня просто не одни чек боксы, я для примера привел, очень много разных переменных

Comment: @Давид так что мешает для всего этого написать внешний класс, куда сохранять состояния. Разумным будет в этом классе сделать хештаблицу, куда вы будет по ключу состояние добавлять, чтоб для каждого элемента не создавать член класса.

Answer (score 0):

Возможны несколько вариантов "изменения значения везде, если изменилось в одном месте".
Один из возможных:

1. Все формы, на которых выставленные значения автоматически должны изменяться, наследуем от одного предка. Пусть это будет `TmyCustomForm`. Этот общий предок должен иметь событие, в котором он будет уведомлять об изменении значения.

```pascal
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,  Vcl.Forms, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TChangedValueType = (cvCheckBox, cvSomeEdit, cvSomeDate); // это виды изменяемых значений.

  // это событие, в котором будем ловить изменения
  TChangeValueEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; ChangedType: TChangedValueType; const Value: Variant) of object;


  // общий предок всех форм, на которых значения должны быть одинаковыми.
  TmyCustomForm = class(TForm)
  private
    FOnChangeValue: TChangeValueEvent;
  protected
    // этот метод вызываем в наследниках, если поменялось какое-либо из "общих" значений.
    procedure DoChangeValue(ChangedType: TChangedValueType; const Value: Variant);
  public
    // это метод для установки значений, измененных в другой форме.
    // чтобы не забыть его перекрыть - делаем абстрактным.
    procedure SetValue(ValueType: TChangedValueType; const Value: Variant); virtual; abstract;

    property OnChangeValue: TChangeValueEvent read FOnChangeValue write FOnChangeValue;
  end;

  // это контейнер, содержащий все формы, следующие идее "одинаковых значений"
  TCustomFormContainer = class(TObjectList<TmyCustomForm>)
  private
    FInChange: Boolean;
    procedure OnChangeValue(Sender: TObject; ChangedType: TChangedValueType; const Value: Variant);
  protected
    procedure Notify(const Value: TmyCustomForm; Action: TCollectionNotification); override;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
{ TmyCustomForm }

procedure TmyCustomForm.DoChangeValue(ChangedType: TChangedValueType; const Value: Variant);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnChangeValue) then
    FOnChangeValue(Self, ChangedType, Value);
end;

{ TCustomFormContainer }

procedure TCustomFormContainer.Notify(const Value: TmyCustomForm; Action: TCollectionNotification);
begin
  inherited;
  // если нам добавляется новая форма - регистрируем свой метод для отлова изменений значений.
  if Action = cnAdded then
    Value.OnChangeValue := OnChangeValue;
end;

procedure TCustomFormContainer.OnChangeValue(Sender: TObject; ChangedType: TChangedValueType; const Value: Variant);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // в одной из форм что-то поменяли.
  // отдаем измененное значение всем остальным формам,
  // не допуская бесконечной вложенности.
  if FInChange then
    exit;
  FInChange := True;
  try
    for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
      if Items[i] <> Sender then
        Items[i].SetValue(ChangedType, Value);
  finally
    FInChange := False;
  end;
end;

end.
```

2. Создаем форму (которая должна быть в списке) обычным образом, но меняем ей предка на TmyCustomForm и добавляем на нее чекбокс (chk1):

```pascal
type
  TForm4 = class(TmyCustomForm)
    chk1: TCheckBox;
    procedure chk1Click(Sender: TObject);
  public
    procedure SetValue(ValueType: TChangedValueType; const Value: Variant); override;
  end;

procedure TForm4.chk1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // при изменении значения - вызываем процедуру, которая отработает
  // на всех формах в контейнере.
  DoChangeValue(cvCheckBox, chk1.Checked);
end;

procedure TForm4.SetValue(ValueType: TChangedValueType; const Value: Variant);
begin
  // здесь принимаем изменения, которые сообщил нам контейнер.
  inherited;
  case ValueType of
    cvCheckBox:
      chk1.Checked := Value; // пока работаем только с чекбоксом.
    cvSomeEdit:
      ;
    cvSomeDate:
      ;
  end;
end;
```

3. В главной форме создаем контейнер (не забываем удалить его по завершению работы) и добавляем код для проверки работоспособности:

```pascal
type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FEqualFormsContainer: TCustomFormContainer;
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation
uses
  Unit4;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  FEqualFormsContainer := TCustomFormContainer.Create;
  // создаем, вносим в контейнер и показываем три формы (исключительно для теста)
  FEqualFormsContainer.Add(TForm4.Create(nil));
  FEqualFormsContainer.Add(TForm4.Create(nil));
  FEqualFormsContainer.Add(TForm4.Create(nil));

  for i := 0 to FEqualFormsContainer.Count-1 do
    FEqualFormsContainer[i].Show;
end;

procedure TForm5.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FEqualFormsContainer.Free;
end;
```

Собственно, все.
На всех трех показываемых формах одновременно изменяется значение в чекбоксе.

Остается только добавлять в перечисление свои типы и не забывать в наследниках TmyCustomForm модифицировать метод SetValue (для установки значения извне) и вызывать DoChangeValue для сообщения контейнеру об изменениях.

Приведенный код не лишен недостатков, к примеру - не обрабатывается освобождение формы. Предлагаю эти доработки осуществить самостоятельно.

Вариантами такого подхода можно назвать:

- использование Screen.Forms вместо контейнера
- использование интерфейсов вместо общего предка (вкупе со Screen.Forms)

Comment: Вы настолько круто все описали, что жалко, что вы меня не правильно поняли, возможно я просто не правильно описал суть проблемы. Дело в том, что мне нужно что-бы каждая форма была сама по себе, не нужно если я нажал где-то на один чек бокс, на другой форме это тоже сделалось, нужно как раз таки наоборот, я попробовал все переменные перенести в сам класс формы, работает, но критует при вызове процедур, хрен пойми почему

Comment: В таком случае - вы действительно плохо описали свою проблему. Исходная фраза, от которой я отталкивался - `если на одной форме я нажал на чекбокс, на ней присвоилось значение переменной, то на второй форме сделалось это же самое`.  "Это же самое" <> "совсем наоборот", вам не кажется?
Постарайтесь четко изложить свою проблему. Обычно в правильной постановке вопроса заключена бОльшая часть ответа.

Comment: У меня динамически создаются формы, на них есть различные функции которые срабатывают если чекбокс чекнут, так вот, если на создано две и более форм и на какой-то из этих форм чекнут чек бокс, то на другой форме, на которой он не чекнут, в коде оно будет думать, что он чекнут

Comment: Возможно я как-то плохо обьявил переменные, все они находятся в глобальной секции.